# Problems references the WebEngine

Tags: class, reference, javafx-2, javafx

I'm trying to make a reference of WebEngine

```
public class ClientArea implements Initializable {

public WebEngine engine;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        engine = browser.getEngine();
        engine.load("about:blank");
    }
}
```

for a class in the same file (ClientArea.java)

```
private static class SearchBox extends Region {

        private WebEngine engine; // private or public

        private TextField insertU;
        private Button refreshButton;
        private Button stopButton;
        private Button backButton;
        private Button forwardButton;
        public Button voltarButton;

        public SearchBox() {
        }
}
```

but that does not work, what would it be?

Comment: can you elaborate "does not work", please?

Comment: @Sergey has a reference example of WebEngine?

Comment: have you tried http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/WebViewSample.java.htm ?

Comment: @SergeyGrinev is not what I need, so I have two files. java has the 1st stage and the second has the webengine, I want to show what ta webengine happening on stage as the title, so I need the reference.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. But if you need to transfer webengine instance from one class to another then just make a setter: `SearchBox#setEngine(WebEngine engine)`.

Comment: @SergeyGrinev where to insert this code in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be i don't understand your question. You want to access from a nested class (`SearchBox`) a field (`engine`) of the top level class (`ClientArea`).

It is easy if the nested class **is not** `static`. In this case, the inner class keeps a reference (`ClientArea.this`) to the outer class and could access to its fields and methods.

```
public class ClientArea implements Initializable {
    public WebEngine engine;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        engine = browser.getEngine();
        engine.load("about:blank");
    }

    private class SearchBox extends Region {
        public SearchBox() {
            System.err.println(engine);
        }

        private ClientArea getClientArea() {
            return ClientArea.this;
        }

        private WebEngine getWebEngine() {
            return engine;
        }
     }
}
```

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358/1594933) on the difference between the static nested class ad the inner class.

[The java tutorial on the nested classes.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: Read my answer, the nested class must not be static.

Comment: HI @gontard, and if I want to use in another file. java?
look what happened!
 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/1yMFx.png

Comment: My solution works for inner class. An inner class keeps a reference on its outer class. Unrelated classes have not references between thems (fortunaly)